# How can I enter boot mode with an STM32F411CEU6?

Tags: pcb, stm32

I ordered a PCB with the following schematic based on an STM32F411. As you can see, the NSRT pin is connected to a LP filter. I think I should have connected it to a switch to easily enter boot mode, but I still have 6 external pins: GND, +3V3, SWDIO, SWO, SWCLK, and NRST.

I tried to connect NRST to GND but I still could not enter boot mode.

- First I connected the USB power supply to my laptop.
- I shorted NRST to GND, still could not boot.
- Then I tried pushing BOOT0 to high before plugging the USB connector in.

How can I boot an STM32F411CEU6 with NRST based on the following schematic? Can I still do it with the SWDIO ?

The following picture is from a personal project:

[image]

Comment: May I ask why do you want to enter bootloader, through which interface you want to program the MCU? Through USB pins to MCU perhaps?

Comment: @Justme I would like to program the MCU in DFU mode. Yes, I usually program  the MCU through USB pins.

Comment: Changing C13 can be done without making new board just by changing part. Crystal can be patched by replacing C4 and C5 by zero ohm resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not work with SWD either due to core voltage cap issue.

DFU surely does not work at all because it needs a correctly connected external clock.

And the crystal is not correctly connected.

If it still does not when you fix the crystal connections, try a different crystal.

It does not need to have that high frequency, slower crystals are easier and simpler to get working, and the bootloader appnote recommends to prefer slower than faster crystals for more reliably detecting the crystal frequency.

I have not mentioned any other possible problems, but they should not be showstoppers.

For example, no bypass caps visible in the schematics. If the design really has no MCU bypass caps then it may be an additional reason why it does not work.

There should not be a 10k pull-up on the NRST pin, unless you know what you are doing and know it is needed, so I hope you know you need it.

Also C13 is 1000x too small. The MCU core voltage may be unstable. Changing the cap might fix it, if the regulator voltage never exceeded max ratings.

Comment: could you elaborate more on why SWD will not work ? How can I make sure my circuit is well connected, or boots at least before sending it to production ?

Comment: @mathssoso I said already the C13 is 1000x too small. The internal regulator may not work properly so the MCU core may not be properly powered. You are only showing a small part of the circuit. It cannot be guessed if it will work as a whole. You need to produce few prototypes and fix the errors you see. Unfortunately, many errors are such that they do not always appear, so you need to validate on the prototypes if they work within a safe margin.

Answer (score 2):

Your crystal connections are wrong. The capacitors do to connect that way. The picture below is from the [NUCLEO-F411RE](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f411re.html#overview) [schematic](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/group2/5a/85/d6/9a/34/e2/47/1d/MB1136-DEFAULT-C05_Schematic/files/MB1136-DEFAULT-C05_Schematic.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.MB1136-DEFAULT-C05_Schematic.pdf):

[image]

Comment: This is correct, but it may not be the only reason why it does not work.